# Sublime text command line Name error

Tags: sublimetext

Good Day,

I am trying to run command line stuff from Sublime text's console. Is that possible? doing stuff like "ls" doesn't work

> > > ls
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'ls' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

The Sublime Text [console](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-python-console-and-the-python-api) is actually the built-in Python interpreter, so it only accepts Python commands. You can use the [`os`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html)* module to interact with the operating system. The following commands will give you a directory listing:

```py
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/something')
os.listdir('.')
```

Check out the [Files and Directories](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/os.html#files-and-directories)* section of the docs for more commands.

---

******* Sublime Text 2 uses Python 2.6, while ST3 uses version 3.3. If you're using ST3, just change the `2.6` in the URLs I gave to `3` and you'll get the correct documentation.